# Extract ZIp File Using Library JSZip

Tags: javascript, windows-8, zip, winjs, unzip

I am working in windows 8 using HTML/JS. I am trying to Extract a Zip file which is picked file using FilePicker.

To extract Zip file I am using this [page](http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/09/18/zipping-and-unzipping-files-in-a-winjs-application/).

In this Link there is a function to Extract Zip file `unzipAsync`

```
function unzipAsync(filePath, replaceIfExists) {

    var fileCollisionOption = replaceIfExists ?
        storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting :
        storage.CreationCollisionOption.failIfExists;

    return storage.StorageFile
        .getFileFromPathAsync(filePath)
        .then(getFileAsUint8Array)
        .then(function (zipFileContents) {
            //Create the zip data in memory
            var zip = new JSZip(zipFileContents);

            //Extract files
            var promises = [];
            var lf = storage.ApplicationData.current.localFolder;
            _.each(zip.files, function (zippedFile) {

                //Create new file
                promises.push(lf
                    .createFileAsync(zippedFile.name, fileCollisionOption)
                    .then(function (localStorageFile) {
                        //Copy the zipped file's contents into the local storage file
                        var fileContents = zip.file(zippedFile.name).asUint8Array();
                        return storage.FileIO
                            .writeBytesAsync(localStorageFile, fileContents);
                    })
                );
            });

            return WinJS.Promise.join(promises);
        });
}
```

Before this I added `JSZIP` Library to Project folder.
 Help me, How Can I integrate the Library to my project. Here is my project [Link](http://sdrv.ms/Jx3Ugk)

**Edit:**

```
function getFileAsUint8Array(file) {
    return storage.FileIO.readBufferAsync(file)
        .then(function (buffer) {
            //Read the file into a byte array
            var fileContents = new Uint8Array(buffer.length);
            var dataReader = storage.Streams.DataReader.fromBuffer(buffer);
            dataReader.readBytes(fileContents);
            dataReader.close();

            return fileContents;
        });
}
```

Now it is working with out error. But it is not doing any thing like extracting my file.

**NOTE:**

*- If anyone knows any another way which better than this or other Library which I can use to extract file for WinJS; please suggest me.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did using [Decompressing Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Decompressing-Sample-54178871) by adding C# windows runtime to my JavaScript project

Here is my [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/94dfb066-435c-4ce2-87df-d6732032b54c/extract-zip-file-using-library-jszip?forum=winappswithhtml5#e7213280-2fe5-4e20-ade5-38d526bc8ab9)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm guessing you haven't created a `getFileAsUint8Array` function (or at least, you aren't showing it above). I am doing something similar (although getting the zip file from an XHR call instead). Once I have the zip file and the folder I want to put the zip files in I do something like the code below.

Note, however, that I had to modify this code as I do a few other things, so I haven't tested it exactly as is (and obviously it wouldn't work within your code above).

Here's the (mostly) full code:

```
WinJS.xhr({ "url": zipUrl, "responseType": "arraybuffer" })
    .done(
        function (e) {
            if (!e.getResponseHeader("content-type") === "application/zip") {
                console.error("Remote file was not sent with correct Content-Type: expected 'application/zip', but received '" + e.getResponseHeader("content-type") + "'");
            }

            unzipAndStore(new JSZip(e.response), someLocalFolder);
        },
        function() { /* handle ajax errors */ }
    );

/**
 * @param {JSZip} jszipobj The JSZip object
 * @param {StorageFolder} localFolder The folder to unzip into
 * @return {Promise}
 */
var unzipAndStore = function (jszipobj, localFolder) {
    var promises = [];

    Object.keys(jszipobj.files).forEach(function (key) {
        var fileName;

        // ignore folder entries, they're handled as needed below
        if (/\/$/.test(key)) { return; }

        fileName = jszipobj.files[key].name.match(/[^\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/);
        if (!fileName) {
            console.error("Unable to process zip entry without proper filename: ", jszipobj.files[key].name);
            return;
        }
        fileName = fileName[0];

        promises.push(
            getFolderFromPathRecursive(jszipobj.files[key].name, localFolder)
                .then(
                    function (subFolder) {
                        console.log("creating file in folder: ", fileName, subFolder.name);

                        return subFolder.createFileAsync(fileName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.replaceExisting)
                    }
                )
                .then(
                    function (localStorageFile) {
                        return Windows.Storage.FileIO
                            .writeBytesAsync(localStorageFile, jszipobj.file(jszipobj.files[key].name).asUint8Array());
                    }
                )
        );

    });

    return WinJS.Promise.join(promises);
};

/**
 * Promise completes with the lowest level folder in the given path, 
 * creating subfolders along the way
 * @param {String} path The path to the lowest subfolder you want a reference to
 * @param {StorageFolder} rootFolder The folder to begin at for this iteration
 * @return {Promise}
 */
var getFolderFromPathRecursive = function (path, rootFolder) {
    var normalizedPath = path.replace(/\/?[^\/]+\.[^\.\/]+$/, ""),  // remove a possible filename from the end of the path
        folders = normalizedPath.split(/\//), // get an array of the folders in the path
        subFolderName = folders.shift(); // remove the first folder in the path as the new one to create

    return new WinJS.Promise(function (complete, error) {
        if (!subFolderName || !subFolderName.length) {
            complete(rootFolder);
            return;
        }

        rootFolder
            .createFolderAsync(subFolderName, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
                .then(
                    function (folder) {
                        return getFolderFromPathRecursive(folders.join("/"), folder);
                    },
                    error
                )
                .then(
                    function(folder) {
                        complete(folder);
                        return;
                    },
                    error
                )
    });
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't understand your code. Can you add little more descriptive or any source link would be Helpfull. 

Yes I am miising 'getFileAsUint8Array' function. After adding the function I didn't get conclusion.
Thanks

Comment: There is no source link... that's the code. As for the `getFileAsUnit8Array` function... are you getting a different error? Your question still says you are getting the `undefined` error... are you? Or are you seeing something else?

Comment: Hi, I edit my question., I forgot to change the description  in my post. & I am just fallowing this link [http://blog.appliedis.com/2013/09/18/zipping-and-unzipping-files-in-a-winjs-application/ ] 
You can try with my sample project which is I added. I can't change the edit in my project. Right now I am out from working. Thanks

Comment: You are unable to try with my project I guess, At least Can you mention how can I use your code to extract a file. Now I have file details which is picked using `Filepicker`. But after that I didn't get any clue to integrate your code. Y because I didn't get relevant help about extract file using `WinJS`; Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just didn't have the time to get to this. I'll try to put something together this weekend if I find a free 30 minutes.

Comment: No need.. Please look at my answer.
Any way I glad for your try & time :)

Comment: Glad you got it working! My own solution took a few days to get right, it's not an easy task.